# How to read multiple ORC & OBR segment from HL7 message using HAPI

Tags: java, hl7, hapi

I have following HL7-Message to parse.

```
MSH|^~\&|LIS|LAB1|APP2|LAB2|20140706163250||OML^O21|20140706163252282|P|2.4
PID|1||7015||LISTESTPATIENT12^LISTESTPATIENT12||19730901000000|F
PV1|1||||||LISPHYCDE1^LISPHY001^LISCARE TEST
ORC|NW|LISCASEID15|||||||||||||||NJ||||TCL^TCL
OBR|1|LISCASEID15||28259^Her2^STAIN|||20140706162713|||||||20140706162713|Breast|patho^pathl^pathf|||image1^image1^image1|blk1^blk1^blk1|SPEC14^SPEC14^SPEC14
ORC|XO|LISCASEID15|||||||||||||||NJ||||TCL^TCL
OBR|2|LISCASEID15||28260^Her2^STAIN|||20140706162713|||||||20140706162713|Breast|patho^pathl^pathf|||image2^image2^image|blk2^blk2^blk2|SPEC14^SPEC14^SPEC14
```

I am trying to fetch values from both OBR & ORC segments using HAPI Terser.get() method as follows.

```
Terser t = new Terser(h7msg);
t.get("/.ORDER_OBSERVATION(0)/ORC-1-1"); // Should return NW
t.get("/.ORDER_OBSERVATION(1)/ORC-1-1"); // Should return XO
t.get("/.ORDER_OBSERVATION(0)/OBR-4-1"); // Should return 28259
t.get("/.ORDER_OBSERVATION(1)/OBR-4-1"); // Should return 28260
```

But all the above statements gives following error
 ***"End of message reached while iterating without loop"***

Don't know, what wrong I am doing here.
Guys please help me with proper input to Teaser.get() method, to get above values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the OML^O21 message does not contain multiple ORDER_OBSERVATION. This means you cannot access the element `ORDER_OBSERVATION(1)`, because it does not exist.

Here a representation within 7edit:
[image]

When you parse your OML message with to XML, you can see the real structure of the HL7:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><OML_O21 xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v2xml">
   <MSH>
      <MSH.1>|</MSH.1>
      <MSH.2>^~\&amp;</MSH.2>
      <MSH.3>
         <HD.1>LIS</HD.1>
      </MSH.3>
      <MSH.4>
         <HD.1>LAB1</HD.1>
      </MSH.4>
      <MSH.5>
         <HD.1>APP2</HD.1>
      </MSH.5>
      <MSH.6>
         <HD.1>LAB2</HD.1>
      </MSH.6>
      <MSH.7>
         <TS.1>20140706163250</TS.1>
      </MSH.7>
      <MSH.9>
         <MSG.1>OML</MSG.1>
         <MSG.2>O21</MSG.2>
      </MSH.9>
      <MSH.10>20140706163252282</MSH.10>
      <MSH.11>
         <PT.1>P</PT.1>
      </MSH.11>
      <MSH.12>
         <VID.1>2.4</VID.1>
      </MSH.12>
   </MSH>
   <OML_O21.PATIENT>
      <PID>
         <PID.1>1</PID.1>
         <PID.3>
            <CX.1>7015</CX.1>
         </PID.3>
         <PID.5>
            <XPN.1>
               <FN.1>LISTESTPATIENT12</FN.1>
            </XPN.1>
            <XPN.2>LISTESTPATIENT12</XPN.2>
         </PID.5>
         <PID.7>
            <TS.1>19730901000000</TS.1>
         </PID.7>
         <PID.8>F</PID.8>
      </PID>
      <OML_O21.PATIENT_VISIT>
         <PV1>
            <PV1.1>1</PV1.1>
            <PV1.7>
               <XCN.1>LISPHYCDE1</XCN.1>
               <XCN.2>
                  <FN.1>LISPHY001</FN.1>
               </XCN.2>
               <XCN.3>LISCARE TEST</XCN.3>
            </PV1.7>
         </PV1>
      </OML_O21.PATIENT_VISIT>
   </OML_O21.PATIENT>
   <OML_O21.ORDER_GENERAL>
      <OML_O21.ORDER>
         <ORC>
            <ORC.1>NW</ORC.1>
            <ORC.2>
               <EI.1>LISCASEID15</EI.1>
            </ORC.2>
            <ORC.17>
               <CE.1>NJ</CE.1>
            </ORC.17>
            <ORC.21>
               <XON.1>TCL</XON.1>
               <XON.2>TCL</XON.2>
            </ORC.21>
         </ORC>
      </OML_O21.ORDER>
      <OML_O21.ORDER>
         <ORC>
            <ORC.1>XO</ORC.1>
            <ORC.2>
               <EI.1>LISCASEID15</EI.1>
            </ORC.2>
            <ORC.17>
               <CE.1>NJ</CE.1>
            </ORC.17>
            <ORC.21>
               <XON.1>TCL</XON.1>
               <XON.2>TCL</XON.2>
            </ORC.21>
         </ORC>
         <OML_O21.OBSERVATION_REQUEST>
            <OBR>
               <OBR.1>1</OBR.1>
               <OBR.2>
                  <EI.1>LISCASEID15</EI.1>
               </OBR.2>
               <OBR.4>
                  <CE.1>28259</CE.1>
                  <CE.2>Her2</CE.2>
                  <CE.3>STAIN</CE.3>
               </OBR.4>
               <OBR.7>
                  <TS.1>20140706162713</TS.1>
               </OBR.7>
               <OBR.14>
                  <TS.1>20140706162713</TS.1>
               </OBR.14>
               <OBR.15>
                  <SPS.1>
                     <CE.1>Breast</CE.1>
                  </SPS.1>
               </OBR.15>
               <OBR.16>
                  <XCN.1>patho</XCN.1>
                  <XCN.2>
                     <FN.1>pathl</FN.1>
                  </XCN.2>
                  <XCN.3>pathf</XCN.3>
               </OBR.16>
               <OBR.19>image1</OBR.19>
               <OBR.20>blk1</OBR.20>
               <OBR.21>SPEC14</OBR.21>
            </OBR>
            <OML_O21.PRIOR_RESULT>
               <OML_O21.ORDER_PRIOR>
                  <OBR>
                     <OBR.1>2</OBR.1>
                     <OBR.2>
                        <EI.1>LISCASEID15</EI.1>
                     </OBR.2>
                     <OBR.4>
                        <CE.1>28260</CE.1>
                        <CE.2>Her2</CE.2>
                        <CE.3>STAIN</CE.3>
                     </OBR.4>
                     <OBR.7>
                        <TS.1>20140706162713</TS.1>
                     </OBR.7>
                     <OBR.14>
                        <TS.1>20140706162713</TS.1>
                     </OBR.14>
                     <OBR.15>
                        <SPS.1>
                           <CE.1>Breast</CE.1>
                        </SPS.1>
                     </OBR.15>
                     <OBR.16>
                        <XCN.1>patho</XCN.1>
                        <XCN.2>
                           <FN.1>pathl</FN.1>
                        </XCN.2>
                        <XCN.3>pathf</XCN.3>
                     </OBR.16>
                     <OBR.19>image2</OBR.19>
                     <OBR.20>blk2</OBR.20>
                     <OBR.21>SPEC14</OBR.21>
                  </OBR>
               </OML_O21.ORDER_PRIOR>
            </OML_O21.PRIOR_RESULT>
         </OML_O21.OBSERVATION_REQUEST>
      </OML_O21.ORDER>
   </OML_O21.ORDER_GENERAL>
</OML_O21>
```

This is unfortunately a problem with many parsers like HAPI, they do verify the structure of any message, depending on the type (OML_O21) and also the version. Because if you change from 2.4 to 2.5, you will get a completely different structure.

If you don't care about that structure, you may use a different HL7 parser like [HL7X](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hl7x/) that transforms the hl7 to xml like a delimited file - independent of hl7 message type or version.

Here you find a similar problem on stackoverflow:

[How to parse the Multiple OBR Segment in HL7 using HAPI TERSER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15812283/how-to-parse-the-multiple-obr-segment-in-hl7-using-hapi-terser)

Comment: Now I am using following dirty-logic; For first occurrence I am using /.ORC-1-1 and /.OBR-4-1 to access first set of ORC and OBR. And after that for each repetition I am using /.ORDER_PRIOR(0)/ORC-1-1 and  /.ORDER_PRIOR(0)/OBR-4-1. And if there is more ORC and OBR segments use /.ORDER_PRIOR(1)/ORC-1-1 and  /.ORDER_PRIOR(1)/OBR-4-1. It works fine for me. I can not use HL7X, as it does not support integration with Apache-Camel, but HAPI does, have to stick with HAPI.